# Adding custom service to nagiosgraph

Tags: nagios

I have successfully added nagiosgraph to our nagios installation. I also added a memory checker plugin, from here : http://blog.vergiss-blackjack.de/2010/04/nagios-plugin-to-check-memory-consumption/. However I can't seem to get the graph of this service to be output by nagiosgraph.

The plugin returns a single line like this:

```
 31% (3785 of 11903 MB) used
```

so i added a rule like this to the map file:

```
/output:(\d+)% \((\d+) of (\d+) MB\) used/
and push @s, ['Mem',
        ['Percentage', 'GUAGE', $1],
        ['Used', 'GUAGE', $2],
        ['Total', 'GUAGE', $3] ];
```

I have also read this : http://www.mail-archive.com/nagios-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg36835.html and made sure that `process_performance_data=1` in the nagios conf file.

So far I have no graph for the Mem service on any host, and no rrd file either. I am unsure how to proceed to get this working. The documentation is rather difficult to follow and I haven't managed yet to understand it enough to do this.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial, or some documentation which explains the steps needed to get a service noticed and graphed by nagiosgraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like your plugin does not return any performance data. have a look at Host State Information. Can you see Performance Data like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. This was indeed the problem, so I've marked this as the correct answer, even though I found out independently. Also I had misspelled 'GAUGE' :-D